# Error running dockerized Neo4j instance in EC2 after small update, reads "Neo4j is already running (pid:7)"

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I spun up the containerized neo4j instance in EC2, it ran fine and was able to perform many graph operations. But I needed to use the APOC library, which required me to place the APOC jar file into the plugins folder of the neo4j container instance (this is all done inside EC2 through command line). So I used the scp command to move the jar file from my local machine to the ec2 instance. Then after that I executed this docker command: `docker restart myneo4jdb`. After it restarted I checked for all the docker contains running, none showed. But if I ran: `docker ps -a`, I could see it's there but `exited after (1) second`, I spent a few hours trying different things in the `neo4j.conf` file but nothing worked. I even removed the conf file completely and restarted it, nothing.

The error log says this `Neo4j is already running (pid:7)` I checked all the processes running using: `ps aux`, pid isn't even shown there. GPT says there might be lock or some other thing that is preventing it from running/thinking neo4j is running. Again, there is no other containers running so not sure what else could be causing this.

When you google that exact error you'll find only three results:

1. [Neo4j process running in background even when the docker container isn't running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76425752/neo4j-process-running-in-background-even-when-the-docker-container-isnt-running)
2. https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/13287
3. https://blog.csdn.net/qq_41081716/article/details/132160977

The first one says to remove the container. But it's production data, removing this would undo months of work, maybe if I could migrate it, or some other workaround is possible?

I had an issue before where anytime I'd add a library it should require the neo4j.conf to be edited and then it worked, so maybe there is more to that. But there error log seems to point to the pid:7 error.

Any help would be great, been at this for a day.

Tutorial I followed to install neo4j container on ec2:
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/introduction/

Comment: I'd avoid `docker {re,}start` in most cases.  Since the container filesystem isn't "clean" you can run into issues with stale pid files and the like that can result in issues like this.  Deleting and recreating the container is usually safer.  If you use the same `docker run -v` option to mount the same external storage to the new container, you won't lose data.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks! At this point what would be the best course of action to take after re-starting the container and it showing this PID, if I run docker rm this would remove all the production data right? Is there a way to save the data? It's currently there is an exited state and any time I run docker start it quickly exits out with the pid:7 error.

Comment: If you didn't start the container initially with a `docker run -v` option, it will inevitably lose data.  Back it up _now_, with whatever means you have available to you.  You need to delete and recreate the container for some very routine actions like changing published ports or taking security updates to the underlying image.

Comment: @DavidMaze Is there a way to copy the database or do a data dump and load. I made another post about this. Moving forward, I need to ensure that I have backup copies of the database.

Comment: Can't help with the docker and process running part. but you can specify that you want apoc via `--env NEO4J_PLUGINS='["apoc"]'` see https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/plugins/ for details